# C: Swapping musical keyboard notes using call by reference

Tags: c

I need to make a C program which provides for users to play a song and create a song via PC keyboard.  My teacher was satisfied enough with my code below and the output produced from it, but he said that I still need to demonstrate knowledge **pointer** use and **function call by reference** in order to pass the subject.

My plan is to create a function that can swap the musical notes in Option 2 (i.e Digital keyboard). For example, Q ordinarily represents a C note and W represents a C sharp (C#) note, but I want the user to have the ability to swap between the two letters, making Q represents C# note and W represents C note.

So the question is, starting from the code below, how can I provide for the user to swap the musical notes in Option 2, and how can I make use of call by reference for that purpose?  I think the selection structure I used in this coding (i.e switch..break) is not suitable if I want to continue to use call by reference but I literally do not know how to start.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>         /* The windows.h library define the beep() and sleep() functions. */

int main()                   /* The function main */
{
char ch;
do                       /* The loop do..while is used so that the program continuously prompt the user to make a choice. */
{
    printf("\nMain Menu\n");
    printf("_________\n\n");
    printf("1- Play 'Twinkle Twinkle Little Star'.\n");
    printf("2- Digital keyboard.\n");
    printf("3- Exit this program.\n\n");
    printf("Your choice >>> ");
    scanf(" %c", &ch);
    if (ch =='1') {       /* The user is given an arithmetic choice from 1 until 3. */
        printf("\nNow playing 'Twinkle Twinkle Little Star'");
        fflush(stdout);
        Beep (261.63,600);Beep (261.63,600);Beep (392.00,600);Beep (392.00,600);Beep (440.00,600);Beep (440.00,600);Beep (392.00,600);
        Sleep(800);
        Beep (349.23,600);Beep (349.23,600);Beep (329.63,600);Beep (329.63,600);Beep (293.66,600);Beep (293.66,600);Beep (261.63,600);
        Sleep(800);
        Beep (392.00,600);Beep (392.00,600);Beep (349.23,600);Beep (349.23,600);Beep (329.63,600);Beep (329.63,600);Beep (293.66,600);
        Sleep(800);
        Beep (392.00,600);Beep (392.00,600);Beep (349.23,600);Beep (349.23,600);Beep (329.63,600);Beep (329.63,600);Beep (293.66,600);
        Sleep(800);
        Beep (261.63,600);Beep (261.63,600);Beep (392.00,600);Beep (392.00,600);Beep (440.00,600);Beep (440.00,600);Beep (392.00,600);
        Sleep(800);
        Beep (349.23,600);Beep (349.23,600);Beep (329.63,600);Beep (329.63,600);Beep (293.66,600);Beep (293.66,600);Beep (261.63,600);
        printf("\nChoose 1 to play again.");
        }
    else if (ch =='2') {
        char m, filename[100];      /* The array declaration of variable that holds the name of the user's file. */
        printf("\nThis is a digital keyboard.\n\n");
        printf("Please enter any UPPERCASE letters and press 'Enter' to play some notes.\n");
        printf("Please don't enter any other characters besides the representations.\n");
        printf("Using other characters would make no sound.\n\n");

        printf("Use number '1' to delay the notes for 0.5 seconds.\n");
        printf("To return to main menu, please enter number '0'\n");
        printf("Using numbers other than '0' and '1' would make no sound.\n\n");

        printf("The notes you have played also will be saved in a file.\n");
        printf("Please enter your file name:\n\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(filename);
        FILE *thefile;
        thefile = fopen(filename,"w");
        if (thefile == NULL)
        {
            printf("File fail to open\n");
        }

        printf("\nRepresentation:\n\n");
        printf("Q -> C    |  W -> C#   |  E -> D    |  R -> D#   |  T -> E    |  Y -> F \n\n");
        printf("U -> F#   |  I -> G    |  O -> G#   |  P -> A    |  A -> A#   |  S -> B \n\n");
        printf("D -> C1   |  F -> C1#  |  G -> D1   |  H -> D1#  |  J -> E1   |  K -> F1 \n\n");
        printf("L -> F1#  |  Z -> G1   |  X -> G1#  |  C -> A1   |  V -> A1#  |  B -> B1 \n\n");
        printf("\t\t\t  N -> C2   |  M -> C2# \n\n");

/* I plan to make the swapping at here */

        do
        {
            scanf("%c",&m);
            switch(m)
            {
            case 'Q' : Beep (261.63,600);break;
            case 'W' : Beep (277.18,600);break;
            case 'E' : Beep (293.66,600);break;
            case 'R' : Beep (311.13,600);break;
            case 'T' : Beep (329.63,600);break;
            case 'Y' : Beep (349.23,600);break;
            case 'U' : Beep (369.99,600);break;
            case 'I' : Beep (392.00,600);break;
            case 'O' : Beep (415.30,600);break;
            case 'P' : Beep (440.00,600);break;
            case 'A' : Beep (466.16,600);break;
            case 'S' : Beep (493.88,600);break;
            case 'D' : Beep (523.25,600);break;
            case 'F' : Beep (554.37,600);break;
            case 'G' : Beep (587.33,600);break;
            case 'H' : Beep (622.25,600);break;
            case 'J' : Beep (659.25,600);break;
            case 'K' : Beep (698.46,600);break;
            case 'L' : Beep (739.99,600);break;
            case 'Z' : Beep (783.99,600);break;
            case 'X' : Beep (830.61,600);break;
            case 'C' : Beep (880.00,600);break;
            case 'V' : Beep (932.33,600);break;
            case 'B' : Beep (987.77,600);break;
            case 'N' : Beep (1046.50,600);break;
            case 'M' : Beep (1108.73,600);break;
            case '1' : Sleep(500);break;
            }
            fputc(m, thefile); /* This will put all the character values that entered by the user into a file. */
        }
        while(m!='0');         /* Users can continue inserting characters until they insert zero.  */
        fclose(thefile);
    }
    else if (ch =='3')
        break;
    else
        printf("Invalid character.\n"); /* This will prevent the user from entering irregular input. */

    }
    while(ch != '3');        /* A sentinel value of 3 allow the user to quit the program. */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Simple solution: you can use an array where index is the key pressed and the item value is an enum of notes used into the switch. Best using array of struct.

Comment: Sidetone: Hmm... "A" normally represents the C note and ("W" == C#, "S" == D)... an octave switch would be far more effective (octave up normally maps to X and octave down normally maps to Z).

Answer (score 0):

> I still need to demonstrate knowledge pointer use and function call by reference.

C does not have call by reference.  Presumably your teacher wants you to demonstrate providing data to a function by passing a pointer to that data, but if he really called that "pass by reference" then he was sloppy.  C provides for passing pointers by value -- that has a similar effect, but it's not quite the same thing.

> My plan is to create a function that can swap the musical notes in Option 2 (i.e Digital keyboard).

That seems both a little weird and potentially tricky.  Allow me to suggest an alternative: create a function that plays songs, and that receives the notes to play via a pointer to an array (or two) of them.  Add a second song to your program's repertoire (e.g. "Mary Had a Little Lamb"), so that you can use the same function to play your choice of those songs depending on that function's arguments.

The prototype for such a function might look like this:

```
void play_song(float *pitch, int *duration, int num_notes);
```

You would combine that with arrays of pitches and notes, such as:

```
float twinkle_pitch[TWINKLE_NUM_NOTES] =
        { 261.63, 261.63, 392.00, 392.00, /* etc */ };
int twinkle_duration[TWINKLE_NUM_NOTES] =
        {    600,    600,    600,    600, /* etc */ };
/* and similar for one or more other songs */
```

Your main program would play a selected song by calling the function, for example,

```
play_song(twinkle_pitch, twinkle_duration, TWINKLE_NUM_NOTES);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, all function arguments are passed ``by value.'' This means that the called function is given the values of its arguments in temporary variables rather than the originals.

The only way to achieve call by reference is use pointers as argument of function.

example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void call_by_value_inc(int formal_argument)
{
    ++formal_argument;
    return;
}



void call_by_reference_inc(int *formal_argument)
{
    ++(*formal_argument);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    int actual_argument = 1;
    call_by_value_inc(actual_argument);
    /*after invoke call_by_value_inc,the actual_argument's value still be 1*/
    printf("actual_argument %d\n", actual_argument);

    call_by_reference_inc(&actual_argument);
    /*after invoke call_by_value_inc,the actual_argument's value will be 2*/
    printf("actual_argument %d\n", actual_argument);
}
```